# Bind not forwarding query after upgrade from 9.11 to 9.16

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am uses Bind at FreeBSD 12.1 server, as DNS back-end of samba DC.

In my configuration local subnet database is stores in samba ldap and to resolve global domain names uses forwarders dns option.

I updated Bind from 9.11 to 9.16 with the same compile options and after this global name resolving stoped to working with the next message:

```
root@Desk1:~ # nslookup google.com 192.168.0.19
Server:         192.168.0.19
Address:        192.168.0.19#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

My named.conf:

```
options {
    directory   "/usr/local/etc/namedb/working";
    pid-file    "/var/run/named/pid";
    dump-file   "/var/dump/named_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/stats/named.stats";
    auth-nxdomain yes;
    notify no;
    empty-zones-enable no;
    tkey-gssapi-keytab "/var/db/samba4/bind-dns/dns.keytab";
    minimal-responses yes;

    allow-query { 127.0.4.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };

    allow-recursion { 127.0.4.1; 192.168.0.0/24; };

    forwarders { 192.168.0.1; 192.168.0.2; };

    allow-transfer { 192.168.0.0/24; key dns.example.local; };
    
    listen-on { 127.0.4.1; 192.168.0.19; };

    query-source address * port 53;

    rate-limit { responses-per-second 15; window 5; };
    tcp-clients 1000000;
##  bind916 options
    dnssec-validation no;
#   auto-dnssec off;
    recursion yes;
#   forward only;
};

zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/named.root";
};

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/master/localhost-forward.db";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/master/localhost-reverse.db";
};

logging {
    channel update_debug {
        file "/var/log/named-update.log";
        severity debug 3;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel security_info {
        file "/var/log/named-auth.log";
        severity info;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
    };
    channel querylog {
        file "/var/log/named-debug.log";
        severity debug 10;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-time yes;
    };
    category update { update_debug; };
    category security { security_info; };
    category queries { querylog; };
};

include "/var/db/samba4/bind-dns/named.conf";
```

I tried to set some option from release notes for Bind 9.16 and search any solutions, but no result.

Some time ago, when Bind 9.14 not yet deprecated - all  worked fully and without any troubles. After some unlucky experimets with updating to 9.16 I needed to downgrade to 9.11.

Ideas?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: I see query in log. Its all, that I see. I'm not fully understand, how turn on verbose mode in bind. Because debug 10 mode show me not all operations inside server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is unclear from the question, but what is clear is that you have trouble with your logging configuration in particular and troubleshooting in general.
I'll focus on those aspects instead as the actual problem is quite possibly trivial once you can see the log.

#### Logging

The way your `logging` configuration is overridden is very likely the reason why cannot find the problem.

Even just going back to the default logging behavior (ie, if you were to rip out the whole `logging` part from your config) you should have an acceptable baseline in terms of at least basic troubleshooting.

To make your current config better, I would strongly suggest also sending the `default` category (catches all categories that you have not created specific configuration for) somewhere.
You are currently throwing away most types of log messages (everything but `update`, `security` and `queries`).
I would expect that for instance the `resolver` or `network` categories could be relevant to the problem, but as I noted `default` would catch "everything else" so that is probably a better idea than starting to guess from the quite long list of categories.

For troubleshooting it can in also sometimes be useful to start BIND with `named -g` (starts named in the foreground, with log output in the terminal), but I suggest fixing the logging configuration regardless.

#### Configuration/data validity

If there was a problem in this regard it should show in the log (after the fix noted above!), but there is also tooling specific for this purpose.

Something like

```
named-checkconf -zj
```

would be helpful for a baseline check that the config + data is "ok" (checks that config+zones are possible to load, not necessarily good).

#### Other configuration problems, unlikely to be related to the problem at hand

There are also some entries in the configuration in the question that just seem really bad. Unless there really is some good reason for these, I would strongly suggest removing them:

```
auth-nxdomain yes;
```

Forces BIND to send incorrect NXDOMAIN responses for non-authoritative NXDOMAIN responses. Why would you want this?

```
query-source address * port 53;
```

Forces the source port to be 53 for outbound queries, while the only really acceptable practice (and default) is to use randomization from a large span of ports. Your config opens up for spoofed responses abuse.

```
dnssec-validation no;
```

Disables DNSSEC validation, further opening up for abuse.

Comment: Thank you! "query-source address * port 53;" - is the problem line and right now do not remember, why its there.

Comment: "auth-nxdomain yes;" - from samba guide, I never think about reasons of appearance this line there. https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_BIND_DNS_Server#Setting_up_a_named.conf_file "dnssec-validation no;" - its my tries to disable new defaults from 9.16, Its not nessesary now.

Comment: Posts like this - where you teach people how to configure logging and do basic troubleshooting - cannot receive enough upvotes. Thank you for taking the taking the time to write all this out!

Answer (score -1):

The problem probably is that they only support up to version 9.12 a.t.m. or so it seems:

Mind you this is on an ARM processor but my "/var/lib/samba/bind-dns/named.conf" folder that you need to include into the bind named.conf only contains links for versions up to 9.12.

```
dlz "AD DNS Zone" {
    # For BIND 9.8.x
    # database "dlopen /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9.so";

    # For BIND 9.9.x
    # database "dlopen /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_9.so";

    # For BIND 9.10.x
    # database "dlopen /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_10.so";

    # For BIND 9.11.x
    # database "dlopen /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_11.so";

    # For BIND 9.12.x
    # database "dlopen /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/samba/bind9/dlz_bind9_12.so";
};
```

Maybe try using the latest version. Might work.